# preview Core Data entity in ChildView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have a Core Data entity named ToDoItem. It has 2 attributes: createdAt (Date) and title (String). Codegen for the entity is Class Definition which looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class ToDoItem: NSManagedObject {

}
```

I am passing this entity to ChildView using this code inside ForEach list:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ChildView(todoItem: todoItem))
```

And in ChildView I have:

```
var todoItem: ToDoItem
```

What's the correct code for Preview in ChildView? I have tried the following and it doesn't work:

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChildView(
            todoItem: ToDoItem
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'ToDoItem.Type' to expected argument type
>   'ToDoItem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked:

```
struct ChildView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        //Test data
        let todoItem = ToDoItem.init(context: context)
        todoItem.createdAt = Date()
        todoItem.title = "Title"
        return ChildView(todoItem: todoItem).environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}
```

What helped me was an answer from Don Nissen, who posted his code here:
[SwiftUI Preview canvas and Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777915/swiftui-preview-canvas-and-core-data)