# Preview crashes when saving to core data but simulator works

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui, simulator, preview

I am creating a simple to do list in swiftUI. When saving tasks to core data in the preview, it crashes. using the simulator works fine however. I tried re-opening the project and looking for similar questions online, but have not found anything yet.
It would be great if anyone could help me, I am new to IOS and Xcode. Thanks a lot!
Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) private var tasks:
        
        // gets stuff from entity "Task" in datamodel
        FetchedResults<Task>
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    @State var cat: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack{
        
            TextField("Enter Task Name", text: $name)
            
            TextField("Enter Task Category", text: $cat)
            
            Button(
                action: {
                    
                    let newTask = Task(context: viewContext)
                    
                    
                    newTask.name = name
                    newTask.category = cat
                    
                    do{
                        try viewContext.save()
                    }
                    catch{
                        let error = error as NSError
                        fatalError("unresolved error:\(error)")
                    }
                },
                label:{
                    Text("Save Task")
                }
            )
            
            List{
                ForEach(tasks, id:\.self){
                    task in Text(task.name ?? "untitled")
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your preview also need a managed object context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Preview canvas and Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777915/swiftui-preview-canvas-and-core-data)

Comment: Are there any error messages? There usually are, and they're usually a key part of understanding what's wrong.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how do I do that?

Comment: @TomHarrington sadly the debug console shows no error messages!

Comment: Maybe some more context would help: The app opens fine in preview, but as soon as I press the button that is supposed to add a todo into core-data, it crashes. In that case the preview gives me a black screen saying "Preview Crashed". I don't see any specific error messages though

Comment: Did you look at the linked question? Also, this is often covered in tutorials for Core Data and SwiftUI

Comment: Yes I checked out the linked question. It seems one needs a work around or simply use simulator, as this behavior is not yet implemented by default in preview. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using this

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
```

So you need to pass that in.

```
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)
}
```

> When using a context in previews, set it up with the
> `NSPersistentStoreDescription` type of `NSInMemoryStoreType`.